Apache Solr Unable to Store Nested JSON data into correct format
i am trying to load the following data into an existing SOLR(8.11) core using the document upload section
The JSON file is :
{
  
  "StudyId": "232H",
  "LastUpdatedDate": "2005-06-24",
  
  "Status": "UNKNOWN",
  
  "NCTId": "HCN00002219",
  
  "Location": [
    {
      "Address": "St. Petersburg, Noida, Delhi, 201306",
      "Coordinates": "27.77086 -82.67927",
      "FacilityName": "All Children's Hosp",
      "LocationStatus": "N/A"
    },
    {
      "Address": "New Orleans, Kanpur, Uttar Pradesh, 70112",
      "Coordinates": "29.95465 -90.07507",
      "FacilityName": "Tulane Univ Med Ctr ",
      "LocationStatus": "N/A"
    }]
}

I have to store and retrieve the Location data as it is .Can anyone please suggest on this .
When we index it as string or text it is removing all the quotes.
"Location":["{LocationStatus=N/A, Address=Los Angeles, California, United States, 90033}",
          "{LocationStatus=N/A, Address=San Francisco, California, United States, 94110,

My schema is,
<field name="Location" type="text_general"/>

I want to store the location and its value in double quotes as it is
